# Margins push sidebar to bottom when Wordpress theme installed

Tags: wordpress, css, margin, sidebar

new to the forum here-

I developed the Wordpress theme that I want to use for my blog- and it looks good on the test site: http://flashandshine.com/eyesofstyletheme/

But when I upload it to my blog: http://eyesofstyle.com/

the nav menu doesn't have the background color, isn't static, and isn't at the top. When you click a post and view a post page, the sidebar is right where I want it. I'm confused as to why it's pushed to the botom on the home blog page.

I was hoping to change this theme around and sell it as a template, but I can't have it moving the sidebars to the bottom! Can anyone help me out with this? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Well, you’ve got a bit of work ahead of you before that is in a “sell-able” state … http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://eyesofstyle.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sell this, it will need some major overhauling.

Looking at the `CSS`, you have some very extreme oddities. The main one being that you are using margins to determine the spacing from the sides instead of making a main container which sets the width.

To get it looking sort of alright, change the `#blogcontent` to show this:

```
#blogcontent {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 17%;
    max-width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
```

Overall though, you will want to change things around a great deal.

This is how you should really want your layout to be using a proper grid layout. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/66KYm/1/).

Its all stuff you pickup along the way though. Hopefully this helps push you in the right direction though.

Comment: I did, but it pushed the sidebar to the bottom.

Comment: On mine its showing fine, can you get a screenshot or something to show how it looks.

Comment: Ok nevermind, it is working now. Any idea why the nav menu didn't carry the styles from the theme?

Comment: This is a css related problem. Within your css, go to line 362 and where it says `.menu-menu-1-container {` change it to `.menu-menu-1-container, .menu-main-nav-container {` and it should work. if it does, itd be awesome if you could give me an upvote and tick for the answer :)

Comment: I actually did that earlier and it worked- I'd give you an upvote, but I guess I have to have 15 reputation :( I guess I wanted to figure out why it didn't change the name of the menu to what the css for the theme says... I would hate for someone to download this theme and have it not work... but like you said it needs a lot of overhaul. It's fine now for what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wordpress isnt that smart to figure that out sadly. You'll need something within your functions.php file to preset the header names so that you can use the correct css names. and i think you can accept it still. which gives you points too